# How do I use py2exe with paver?

Tags: python, py2exe, paver

I'm using paver to build my Python application, and I'd like to create an executable using py2exe.  I've got the following in my pavement.py:

```
from paver.setuputils import setup
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import paver
paver.setuputils.install_distutils_tasks()
```

... but when I run `paver py2exe` I get "Build failed: py2exe is not a Task".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial), you just pass your "main" python script to the `setup` command:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Have you tried building your execuable this way?

Comment: I'm using paver, not distutils

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting paver's setup with distutils one.

Also, calling `paver.setuputils.install_distutils_tasks()` is not needed; just call setup in same was as You do in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I too am trying to use py2exe from paver.  However, I ran into [the problem described here](http://groups.google.com/group/paver/browse_thread/thread/5eb90f12298edc5a/1e14403b32152f42) and from that (and some other googling around) my conclusion is that the two aren't integrated and that the cleanest thing to do is to maintain a separate setup.py for py2exe and hope [distutils2](http://distutils2.notmyidea.org/) improves things.

However, I would be very happy to be proven wrong..